# How to move the Google Chart's annotation to the top or anywhere with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

I would like to move the annotation to the bottom or the top of the Google Chart API as the image below. I've tried with `magin-bottom: 50px`, `padding-bottom: 50px` or `bottom: 50px` but these didn't work to me.

[image: Pic]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you get this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/AW5UR/)** working ?

Comment: @ImranBughio: It doesn't work. What's wrong with it? Please press Run before Saving!

Comment: @ImranBughio: It works now with http://jsfiddle.net/AW5UR/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a option to move bottom using "legend" keyword.

Update your options part like below.

```
var options = {
  legend: 'bottom',
  title: 'Company Performance'
};
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AW5UR/2/)

Comment: That's great. It works well with `legend: 'top'` and `legend: 'bottom'`. Thank you so much.